# Scrolling window without using Control key in Vim

Tags: windows, vim, scroll

Is it possible to scroll window screen without using `control + U` or `control + D`, (or `control + F,B,E` etc). I am aware that I can use 'j' or 'k', but that is a line by line scroll. I am looking to scroll through a larger chunk of text without using `control` key. I find it little inconvenient to move from home row. (May be I am thinking too much.)

I am aware that I can use `/`search or `nG` to move to a particular line. But sometimes, it is helpful to scroll through the code, without a specific line.

I am using GVim (windows). Thank you.

Comment: With only nine alphabetic keys on your home row, writing this question must have been a torture.

Comment: I suppose, I don't have to write this question, hundred times a day, every day! The point is not to have keys in home row, but something that may be little bit easier.

Answer (score 3):

`<C-U>` / `<C-D>` scroll by `'scroll'` number of lines. You can emulate that via

```
:execute 'normal!' &scroll . 'j'
```

This is too long to type, so you need a mapping, but that probably again would involve a modifier key. For ad-hoc scrolling, just estimate the amount of lines and type `30j`.

That said, modifier keys are important in Vim (even if less than in Emacs). Maybe you should consider remapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, for example to <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>?

Comment: I like the `30j` suggestion. Better still, turn on relative line numbers and no more guessing.

Comment: And less thinking, would be the quicker vim-tap: `33j`.

Answer (score 0):

As I wise friend once showed me, you can use `L` to move cursor to the
bottom of the current window frame. Similarly, you can use `H` to go to
the top, or `M` to go to the middle, and also you can then scroll to
center the frame on the cursor location with `zz`.

With that, you can scroll down with `L zt`, and up with `H zb`. Half
scroll with `L zz`, `H zz`.

Better yet, if you're using spacemacs, you can use `SPC N f` or `SPC N b` to scroll forward and back. Either of which will put you in transient
state, meaning after you enter `SPC N f` subsequent commands are without
the prefix: `f`, `b`, `u`, `d`, until you exit the state.